# .htaccess time on godaddy

Tags: godaddy, 500-error, cakephp

I'm trying to run a cakephp application on a godaddy linux account. The problem is that i get the error 500. I've read on cakephp discussion group that i have to edit the .htaccess file.

1) How much do i have to wait until i see the result?
2) *More information about this error may be available in the server error log.* Where are those servers log on a godaddy linux hosted account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Richard Holloway is correct about the .htaccess files. Changes take effect immedietly.

As for the error logs, GoDaddy has a specific way of accessing them:

http://help.godaddy.com/article/1197

> To View Error Logs
>
> 1. Log in to your Account Manager.
> 2. In the My Products section, select
>      Hosting.
> 3. Next to the hosting account you want
>      to modify, click Manage Account.
> 4. In the Settings section of the
>      Hosting Control Center, click the
>      Error Logs icon.
> 5. Click View Logs.
> 6. Log in using your hosting account
>      username and password.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I thought they would provide a user interface for this but I have never used GoDaddy myself. This is useful information.

Answer (score 2):

1) Changes to .htaccess files will take effect immediately.

If you are being advised to edit the .htaccess files this suggests that your .htaccess files may contain php_values or php_flags that will need to be removed.

For example your .htaccess file  may contain

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
```

This example could then be added to a php.ini file like this

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

2) The error details will be added to the log file. As you have a Linux account the logs will likely be /var/log/httpd/error.log or /var/log/apache2/error.log depending on which distribution you are running.

Alternatively you may have access to cPanel or another control panel in which case there will possibly a way to view the logs there.